# Why do web services keep asking me about my phone number?

Tags: web-application, privacy

They say it's for my own safety and that somehow my account is more "secure" if I link it with my phone number, but I don't understand why - they already have my e-mail address through which I can reset passwords. Also, what is the impact on my privacy if I give a phone number to a web service? What can they use it for?

In other words - what do I gain, and what does the service provider gain from linking my phone number to my account?

Comment: It's harder to steal a phone number.  You gain security.  They gain a phone number to sell to some numbskull who calls you saying he is with the IRS and is sending the police to arrest you.

Comment: Most web services explain that they would use your phone number in order to send text messages instead of emails when you need account service

Comment: The main reason is to make it harder for spammers to open accounts. It's easy to get a throwaway email address, but a throwaway phone number is more difficult.

Comment: Unless the web service is a banking website or a government e-service portal where security is important, I suggest you not to offer your phone number if you value your privacy.

Comment: What I find most ironic about the use of phone numbers is, that they are less permanent than email addresses... I still have a 10 year old email address - I had a few phone numbers since then... (Because it is a hassle to port over numbers when moving to a different provider and it is easier to share the new number, or because I moved to another country.)

Comment: @paj28 Ever heard of prepaid SIM cards? - Getting a throwaway number is absolutely trivial. Yes, you cannot "mass collect them", but changing a phone number say every month would not be difficult. Now in Germany and France you do jump through additional hoops with ID, but in England you just walk into a shop, buy a prepaid SIM and leave.

Comment: @DetlevCM - Of course I've heard of them. Walking into a shop is more difficult than getting a thowaway email. Also, if someone's committing crime, this reveals their location, and the phone shop may have CCTV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***EDIT:*** *As this is still the accepted answer, I've made a number of changes to the below text to clarify that, while the "why" is still "probably for multi-factor authentication", this method is not trustworthy.*

---

A phone number enables an easy way to set up two-factor authentication for things like password resets or other sensitive actions. By calling you or sending a text message, the service can confirm that [access to] the phone [number] is a **thing you have**. An email account is really just a **thing you know**, the same as a password, because you can access it without anything other than a password (and the identifier - in this case, the address itself - but identifiers are generally considered public). Thus, a two-factor password reset flow might go something like this:

1. Click on "Forgot my password" at login.
2. Enter your email address, and the site sends you a password reset link.
3. Open the password reset link (which contains a secret token), thus proving that the password to your email account is something you **know**.
4. Service sends you a text message with a short secret code in it (possibly after making you confirm your phone number).
5. You enter the code from the message, thus proving that your phone is a thing you **have**.
6. Two-factor authentication being completed, you can now set a new password, log into the site, etc.

The advantage to the service provider is that they are now much less likely to have to spend customer service time and possible customer goodwill walking the line between "I can't remember my password" and "somebody hacked my account". That kind of thing can be a significant cost sink, and if the site contains anything sensitive then it may lead to reputational harm to the site if they aren't paranoid enough.

Unfortunately, hijacking mobile numbers is not that hard to do. Even leaving aside technical attacks (faked cell towers or spoofing the phone or passively sniffing the radio traffic to catch the SMS that gets sent), phone companies have demonstrated that they are not trustworthy when it comes to authenticating people correctly before issuing them a new SIM with your number. As such, SMS or call-based second factors should be considered a weak additional protection, and should *definitely* not be trusted for single-factor authentication.

As for what the provider can do with a number, well, worst case would probably be to give or sell it to robocallers, the telephone equivalent of spam. Calling a mobile number in such a manner is actually illegal in the USA (since we're about the only place in the world that the recipient pays for incoming calls, either via prepaid credit or minutes of usage, so commercial messages without an existing business relationship are forbidden) but they happen anyhow. Realistically, though, any but the sketchiest of sites is unlikely to do anything like this (feel free to check their privacy policy, though of course there's no guarantee it's not a lie).

Second-worst thing would be to use it to send you unsolicited calls or messages, but I don't think I've ever seen this happen (do check for a "use your contact information for marketing or promotions..." option and make sure it's not selected).

In theory, the phone number might be useful to identify you personally (through a directory service / social network / phone book / whatever) and it's a lot easier to create throw-away email addresses than throw-away phone numbers. It's unlikely, though. If you're the kind of person who uses a fake name and a single-use email address when signing up for something, then putting your real phone number in there is obviously a risk. Otherwise, it's probably pretty harmless.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's the easiest way to obtain the second factor (something you have) in [two-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication#Mobile_phone_two-factor_authentication). How this works was explained pretty well in CBHacking's answer. However...

### Using your phone for two-factor auth is a BAD IDEA

The problem with phones is that it's surprisingly easy for hackers to social engineer their way through a telecom's customer service department and port your number to theirs, then use the phone to reset the account password.

It doesn't matter how computer-savvy you are. [People in the cryptocurrency space have been hacked](http://blog.kraken.com/post/153209105847/security-advisory-mobile-phones) this way:

> In the past month, there’ve been at least 10 cases of people publicly involved in the cryptocurrency scene being victimized by mobile phone hijacking.  The consequences have been expensive, embarrassing, enduring, and, in at least one case, life-threatening.

The US Federal Trade Commission has put up an advisory regarding [The Growing Problem of Phone Account Hijacking](https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/blogs/techftc/2016/06/your-mobile-phone-account-could-be-hijacked-identity-thief). More layman's coverage of phone number hijacking was recently in [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/laurashin/2016/12/21/hackers-are-hijacking-phone-numbers-and-breaking-into-email-and-bank-accounts-how-to-protect-yourself/), for example.

Whenever possible, **do not** give your phone number, and choose Google Authenticator as a 2FA method. For more details, see this [excellent guide by cryptocurrency exchange Kraken, or how to secure your online accounts](http://blog.kraken.com/post/153209105847/security-advisory-mobile-phones).

Comment: I don't see how your computer savvy or lack of same would matter here. What does matter is how security-savvy your phone operator is.

Comment: The obvious problem with TOTP (Google Authenticator and friends) as a 2FA solution is that if you lose the device (due to theft, damage, spontaneous failure, bad firmware, glitch requiring a factory reset, etc.), you can't ever get back into the account (unless you stored the TOTP setup key somewhere or were able to back up the app's keys, in which case you have a key storage problem). While some services offer special "recovery keys" usable if you lose your TOTP app (though again, you need to store them...), most only offer SMS as a TOTP alternative, so you have little choice but to enroll.

Comment: Thank you for that link to Kraken, very interesting (and slightly terrifying) read

Comment: @tripleee: yes, that's my point too.

Comment: @CBHacking: correct, you need to add your TOTP keys to the files/things you back up securely. Part of the tradeoff between security and convenience.

Comment: @CBHacking Most companies that provide 2FA via TOTP or the like also have channels for account recovery in case you lose access to your stored keys.  I've had to go through that myself once or twice, and in the cases I have done it their processes are **much** less prone to the social engineering attacks that plague phone carriers (note that I did not say immune).  Presumably the companies that have TOTP enabled are more security-conscious and so adjust their processes accordingly.

Comment: Not only that, but banks sometimes allow a user to add his phone number, change post address, etc. So a hacker can determine all parameters, authenticate, even get a new payment card and code...

Comment: @CBHacking Some TOTP apps such as Authy allow you to sync your TOTP keys across multiple devices, so you’d have to lose all your devices at once to be locked out of your accounts. You have to trust in their security, of course, but that’s not very bad because a TOTP key alone shouldn’t give an attacker access to an account.

Answer (score 2):

I have a hypothesis that it is an identifier (non-social security number) that companies will sell to each other to track everything you do. So far I have been asked by: Vanguard, Fidelity, Bank of America, eBay, Amazon, Netflix, Yahoo, Google, LinkedIn. I think there are more, but I forget. It may be centralized because they all ask in the same manner, with the "not right now" option (never a "no, leave me alone and never ask again" option). The psychotic side of me says it is run by the NSA as an easy way to track you and everything you do (imagine, a single number code that represent an online presence and everything you do! Heaven for government snoops). The rational side of me says it is run by advertisers. Do I think it is for security? Nope. If it is for security then hypothetically you can give a different number to each company (why must it be a real phone number that they can call anyhow? Or can several people use the same shared number? Or can you set up several Skype-in numbers?). 
I am a naturally suspicious person and my alarm bells are going crazy these past few months. Something is not right at all.

Answer (score 0):

Web services keep asking you about your phone number because it is another security layer that to make you think that your account is more secured(due to the fact that it requires you another extra-step to access your account) but as many already said, it's useless in front of a real hacker because hacking phones and doing whatever with phone numbers are not new things. Your phone number also can be used to spy and track you down. A simple experience is to download a dating app, create your account, log in, log out, delete your account, delete the dating app, change your number and later download the same app. Your previous old phone number will pop up when you try to log in.

Comment: This adds absolutely nothing to the existing answers. Did you mean to add a unique perspective?